# Interpreting continuous interaction term

Tags: interpretation, continuous-data, interaction

I have a question regarding the interpretation of an interaction term in the following model:
$$
Y=β_0+β_1X+β_2Z+β_3XZ
$$
$X$ and $Z$ are continuous and $X$ is negatively related to $Y$, whereas $Z$ is positively related to $Y$.

Is it true that a negative interaction ($β_3$=negative) suggest that the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ becomes less negative as the value of $Z$ increases? And a positive interaction ($β_3$=positive) suggests that the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ becomes more negative as the value of $Z$ increases?